# QGIS does not launch

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

QGIS 1.8.0-1 does not launch (nor its companions: Browser, Grass, etc.) neither on machine with Win XP SP3 nor with Win 7 (GRASS installed separately works well). Console displays a message on launch: "'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external operable program or batch file".

I tried all solutions suggested here earlier with no result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have copied findstr.exe (it should be in system32 folder) in the same folder of this.exe, and I have solved.